# How to index all the derived components in a base component list in Entity

Tags: c++, templates, unity-game-engine, enumeration, component-based

I am trying to do a entity component system design for simulation. Here is what confuses me now.
I am trying to make a Entity class

```
Entity.h
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity();
    virtual ~Entity() = 0;
    //---------------------Methods---------------------//
    void AddComponent(const shared_ptr<Component> component);

    template<class T>
    T* GetComponent() const;

    //---------------------Members---------------------//
    vector<shared_ptr<Component>>   m_components;
}

Entity.cpp
template<typename T>
T* Entity::GetComponent() const
{
    Component::component_type_t typeIndex = /*T::component_type*/
    T* returnPtr = dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(m_components[component_type].get());
    return returnPtr;
}
```

And the Component class looks like this

```
class Component
{
public:
    Component();
    virtual ~Component() = 0;
    //---------------------Methods---------------------//

    //---------------------Members---------------------//
    typedef enum component_type_t
    {
        MESH_T,
        RIGIDBODY_T,
        TRANSFORM_T,
        NUM_TYPES
    };
    component_type_t componentType;
};
```

They way I want to use `GetComponent()` is the same as in Unity3D

```
Transform* t = GetComponent<Transform>()
```

But as you can see I cannot find a way to do that yet. The way I used to do it was

```
class Entity
{
    .....
    Component* GetComponent(Component::component_type_t componentType) const
    {
      return m_components[component_type].get()
    };
}
```

And I could only use it as

```
Transform* t = dynamic_pointer_cast<Transform>(GetComponent(Component::component_type_t::TRANSFORM_T));
```

Clearly it is tedious.

So my question is can I use some form as this?

```
class Entity
{
    .....
    template<class T>
    T* GetComponent() const
    {
    Component::component_type_t typeIndex = /*T::component_type*/
    T* returnPtr = dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(m_components[component_type].get());
    return returnPtr;
    };
}
```

I feel the cleanness and the speed to keep using `std::vector<>` for storing all my component pointers, is that also a valid design?

Comment: If you have a look at what unity does you see that every class (component type) you can use `GetComponent` on actually derives from `Component` at some point. You are talking about `derived components`, but you are not using inheritance at all.

Comment: Are you sure you want to implement your template in cpp ?

Comment: The ´Transform´ class is actually inherited from ´Component´, Sorry I didnt mention that

Comment: And yes, I `#include "Entity.cpp"` in the end of header file so it should be OK

Comment: better to rename it `.inl`/`.hxx` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did something similar long time ago. I think you are doing this the hard way. You can easily modify the code below to suit your need. The `Components` are inherited. You can remove the inheritance and replace it with class inside class or all component classes inside the `Component` class.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Vector3
{
    float x, y, z;
    Vector3(float x, float y){}
    Vector3(float x, float y,float z){}
};

template <class T>
class Component
{
public:
    T t;
    void adNewComponent(){

    }
};

class Mesh{
public:
    Mesh(){}
};

class Rigidbody{
public:
    Rigidbody(){}
    void AddForce(float x,float y, float z){}
    void AddForce(Vector3 force){}
};


class Transform{
public:
    Transform(){}
};

class Object{

};

class GameObject:Object,
    Component<Mesh>,
    Component<Rigidbody>,
    Component<Transform>
{
public:
     template <class T>
     T &GetComponent()
    {
        return this->Component<T>::t;
    }

     template <class T>
     T &AddComponent(){
         this->Component<T>::adNewComponent();
         return this->Component<T>::t;
     }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    GameObject gameObject;
    gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Rigidbody rigidBody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rigidBody.AddForce(9,0,0);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is really clever! I used to think I could only use curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) to do that, but you actually get rid off the inheritance, and the pointers vector as well. Bravo!

Comment: I will try it first though

Comment: @XúJiāfēng Sure. Try it and let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: It works. I packed all components  in a ´class ComponentList´ and I then  everytime I write new components I put it into the inheritance list. I also made components as shared_ptr to reserve a pointer space. So for ´class Entity´ I only need to inherit componentList whatsoever and call a template function ´AddComponent´ when I need to add extra components. Thank you very much!